# How to force a class to declare a final variable?

Tags: android, abstract-class, final

For the moment, I created an abstract class like this:

```
public abstract class MyClass {
    public final static String TAG;
    ...
}
```

But it gives me an error of not initializing a final variable. Then I tried to initialize it from a constructor, but it didn't work either (gives the same error plus another one of trying to set a value to a final variable), although many stackoverflow posts says that really works...

```
public abstract class MyClass {
    public final static String TAG;

    public MyClass(String u){
        this.TAG = u;
    }
}
```

It seems like final variables have to be assigned only when declaring the variable. Is this correct? How can I achieve this?

Comment: final means you cannot change the value of the variable. so no set, only get

Comment: I know, I just want TAG variable to be different depending on the class that is implementing MyClass.

Comment: oh sorry, i didnt read the abstract in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can't because of the `static` keyword. `static final` gives you the assurance that the value of the variable will not change for the whole life cycle of the application. When you try to initialize it in the constructor you are bounding its value to the particular instance, defeating the concept of *constant*. Since you want to have a different value for every subclass you could change your code like:

```
public abstract class MyClass {
    protected final String mTag;

    public MyClass(String u){
        mTag = u;
    }
}
```

this way `mTag` only accessible only from  `MyClass`'s subclasses. Or you could also declare it a `constant` in every subclass, omitting the constructor's intialization. E.g

```
public final static String TAG = YourClassName.class.getSimpleName();
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, the code works well if not declaring it static.

Answer (score 1):

> @Corbella said : I just want TAG variable to be different depending on the class that is implementing MyClass

You can try

```
public abstract class MyClass {
    private final String TAG;

    public MyClass(String u){
        this.TAG = u;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return this.TAG;
    }
}
```

Your TAG will only be set by the constructor and you can just access it from the outside via the getter.

Comment: I guess @Blackbelt has a better answer :)

Answer (score 0):

A final variable can be initialized at two points that I know of.

```
final String test = "test1";
```

Or

```
final String test;
if(conditionOneTrue) {
    test = "test2";
} else {
    test = "test3";
}
```

The compiler will only allow you to continue if the test variable is initialized. All routes must lead to the variable being initialized.

In your case, the variable is static. That means that the test variable can be accessed before the class itself is initialized. The compiler is probably noticing that, and telling you to make sure that the final variable is properly initialized. If you remove static, it should work.

Comment: it's either at declaration level or constructor level

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you are using both static and final together. This would mean that all subclasses of this class would have the same TAG. Not something you would like either.

I am assuming you want to use this for logger, you can do something like this in the abstract class and it will print out the subclasses name

```
Log.d("-- onCreate " + this.getClass().getName());
```